# Listbox of numbers

Tags: c, winapi, listbox

I use `SendMessage(hList, LB_SETITEMDATA, pos, (LPARAM) data );` for adding names to listbox.
But How can I add numbers to a listbox?

Comment: Convert the number into a string and use the same method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
wsprintf( data, "%d", 10 );
```